# juniper j2300 console connection?

Tags: networking, router, console, juniper, serial

I've been given a Juniper Networks J2300 router, but I've never used a juniper device before and no idea where to begin on how to connect to the console of the device.

I have a serial to RJ45 cable but not sure on how to connect to the device.

Do I use specific software or just use something like minicom (linux hyperterminal alternative)?

I've had a look on the juniper website and couldn't find anything :(

Any help would be truly appreciated,
cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Minicom will be fine.

Junipers use the 'standard' serial settings, ie:

- Bits per second: 9600
- Data bits: 8
- Parity: None
- Stop bits: 1
- Flow control: None

(9600-8N1)

More informations [here on Juniper's website.](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/software/jseries/junos91/jseries-getting-started/cli-local-connect-section.html)

Answer (score 0):

Any terminal emulator like minicom, putty, Secure CRT ect will work.

just plug it in to the RJ45 console port on the front of the J2300 and hit return a couple of times set up with 9600-N-8-1.

If you are not getting anything you might want to check the flash card located in the back of of the J2300. and also look inside the router at the memory.

[This website](http://www.stevedrake.org/blog/) has some pictures of the inside of a J2300 prior to him removing it to make an "olive".

Answer (score 0):

`screen` running on your `/dev/ttySX` usually does what you want out of the box.